# Type '{}' is not assignable to type `'any[] | Iterable<any> | (Iterable<any> & any[]) | (any[] & Iterable<any>) | null | undefined'`

Tags: angular10

I am trying to run this code and get an error.

```
    this.resto.getList().subscribe((result)=>{     
      console.warn(result)
      this.collection=result;
    })
```

I am getting the error:

```
core.js:7990 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.


Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[] & Iterable<any>'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem

```
collection = <any>{};
```

You can loop over an object in TypeScript, you can also use this:

```
collection = <any>[];
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

`collection = <any>{};` worked for me as well as I was facing the same issue. It can be caused due to object mismatch between what is expected and what is returned in the function.

I would also suggest to include `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` in your `tsconfig.json` file.